# Improving the solution of sparse linear systems

Tags: c++, linux, cuda, sparse-matrix, umfpack

I have written a code in C++ on a Linux system which solves the linear system `A x = b`, where `A` is a sparse symmetric matrix using the following two approaches:

1. Using `UMFPACK` to sequentially factorize and do backward forward substitution.
2. Using `UMFPACK` to sequentially factorize followed by a backward forward substitution using the `cuSPARSE` library.

The system configuration I have is: CUDA version 5.0, `UMFPACK` version 5.6.2, Linux kernel version  Debian 3.2.46-1, graphics card used: GeForce GTX Titan.

Theoretically, the second approach should perform better than the first approach with minimal or no errors. However, I am observing the following problems:

1. The backward/forward substitution using `UMFPACK` function **umfpack_di_solve** is almost `2x` faster than the CUDA variant.
2. For some matrices, the error between the results obtained using `UMFPACK` and CUDA are quite large with the maximum error being `3.2537`, whereas, for other matrices, it is of the order of `1e-16`.

Attached is my tar file with the following components:

- A folder factorize_copy with the main file **fc.cu** that I am using to solve the linear system. It reads the sparse matrices from the **grid_*_CSC.m** files which are also present in the same directory. For convenience, the results with the three sparse matrices provided are also given in the text files.
- A folder with all the dependencies for compiling and running `UMFPACK` (which we are also using for computations).

The link to the tar file is 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qfs5awclshyk3b/code.tar.gz

If you wish to run the code, I have provided a **MAKEFILE** as I use in my system in the factorize_copy directory. You may need to recompile the `UMFPACK` Libraries.

A sample output from our program for a `586 x 586` Sparse Matrix is also shown below (Note that errors for this case are very high as compared to other sparse matrices that we checked).

```
***** Reading the Grids

    Reading Grids Successful

***** Solving a sparse matrix of size: 586x586

***** Solving the grid on umfpack

***** Factorizing The Grid

-------------- CPU TIME for umfpack factorization is: 0.00109107

-------------- Wall-Clock TIME for umfpack factorization is: 0

    Factorizing the Grid successful

    Solving the grid on umfpack successful

-------------- CPU TIME for umfpack solve is: 6.281e-05

***** Allocating GPU memory and Copying data

---------------- CPU Time for Allocating GPU memory and Copying Data: 1.6

***** Performing b = P*b to account for the row ordering in A 

    Matrix-Vector (Pb) multiplication successful

***** Solving the system: LUx=b

    Analyzing Ly = b successful

    Solving Ly = b successful

    Analyzing Ux = y successful

    Solving Ux = y successful

***** Performing x = Q*x to account for the column ordering in A

    Matrix-Vector (Qx) multiplication successful

---------- GPU Time for the solve is: 5.68029 ms

##### Maximum error between UMFPACK and CUDA: 3.2537

##### Average error between UMFPACK and CUDA: 0.699926

***** Writing the results to the output files

    Result Written to the file 'vout_586.m' and the file 'vout_umfpack_586.m'

(Operation Successful!)
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could point out what the possible error could be in this case. If there is a better method of solving sparse linear systems using CUDA that I am missing out, please let me know.

**EDIT:** I figured out why it was giving error in some cases and in some cases not. I had a mistake in the number of threads per block when calling a kernel function in the code. However, I still have the issue of gaining a speed-up.

Comment: Which CPU does your system have? You mention UMFPACK 5.6.2 (which seems to be available), but your tar file seems to have UMFPACK 5.2.0 in it? Does that matter?  Also, in your `Makefile` you are specifying the `-G` switch and not specifying any `-arch` switch.  I would delete the `-G` switch and specify the `-arch=sm_35` switch for your GTX Titan.

Comment: CPU used is: Intel core i7-4770 Quad core processor. The UMFPACK version does not matter.

Answer (score 4):

If you are dealing with a problem which takes sub-ms amounts of time on the CPU, you can hardly expect the gpu to perform faster, given all the latency involved in gpu computation.

Comment: I am doing the system solves inside monte-carlo iterations. The factorization is needed only once, but the backward/forward substitution is performed multiple times inside one monte-carlo iteration. Hence, I was hoping to use GPU for backward/forward solve, so that I don't spend computation time copying data back and forth between main memory and GPU memory. By the way, the same trend is observed for sparse matrices of size 1M or more. Is there any method to overcome this issue and speed-up the solve.

Answer (score 1):

This post considers the very important problem of fast solution of sparse linear systems.

As of November 2015, the `cuSPARSE` library offers routines for the solution of sparse linear systems based on LU decomposition, in particular

```
cusparse<t>csrilu02
```

and

```
cusparse<t>csrsv2_solve
```

Furthermore, `cuSPARSE` offers the

```
cusparse<t>csrcolor
```

which implements **graph coloring**. The use of graph coloring for incomplete LU-factorization is described in

[Graph Coloring: More Parallelism for Incomplete-LU Factorization](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/graph-coloring-more-parallelism-for-incomplete-lu-factorization/)

and

[M.Naumov, P.Castonguay, J. Cohen, “Parallel Graph Coloring with Applications to the incomplete-LU factorization on the GPU”, NVIDIA Research Technical Report, May, 2015](https://research.nvidia.com/publication/parallel-graph-coloring-applications-incomplete-lu-factorization-gpu).

The idea is to apply the graph coloring algorithm to the row dependency graph associated to the coefficient matrix of the system and then reorder the system equation accordingly so that the LU factorization routine can extract more parallelism.

Below, please find a fully worked example using the above idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

#include "Utilities.cuh"

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cusparse_v2.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE   256

/**************************/
/* SETTING UP THE PROBLEM */
/**************************/
void setUpTheProblem(double **h_A_dense, double **h_x_dense, double **d_A_dense, double **d_x_dense, const int N) {

    // --- Host side dense matrix
    h_A_dense[0] = (double*)calloc(N * N, sizeof(*h_A_dense));

    // --- Column-major ordering
    h_A_dense[0][0] = 0.4612f;  h_A_dense[0][4] = -0.0006f; h_A_dense[0][8]  = 0.f; h_A_dense[0][12] = 0.0f; 
    h_A_dense[0][1] = -0.0006f; h_A_dense[0][5] = 0.f;  h_A_dense[0][9]  = 0.0723f; h_A_dense[0][13] = 0.04f; 
    h_A_dense[0][2] = 0.3566f;  h_A_dense[0][6] = 0.0723f;  h_A_dense[0][10] = 0.f; h_A_dense[0][14] = 0.0f; 
    h_A_dense[0][3] = 0.0f;     h_A_dense[0][7] = 0.0f;     h_A_dense[0][11] = 1.0f;    h_A_dense[0][15] = 0.1f; 

    h_x_dense[0]    = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double)); 
    h_x_dense[0][0] = 100.0;  h_x_dense[0][1] = 200.0; h_x_dense[0][2] = 400.0; h_x_dense[0][3] = 500.0;

    // --- Create device arrays and copy host arrays to them
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_dense[0], N * N * sizeof(double)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A_dense[0], h_A_dense[0], N * N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_x_dense[0], N * sizeof(double)));   
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_x_dense[0], h_x_dense[0], N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
}

/************************/
/* FROM DENSE TO SPARSE */
/************************/
void fromDenseToSparse(const cusparseHandle_t handle, double *d_A_dense, double **d_A, int **d_A_RowIndices, int **d_A_ColIndices, int *nnz, 
                       cusparseMatDescr_t *descrA, const int N) {

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA[0]));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatType     (descrA[0], CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrA[0], CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO));  

    nnz[0] = 0;                             // --- Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix
    const int lda = N;                      // --- Leading dimension of dense matrix

    // --- Device side number of nonzero elements per row
    int *d_nnzPerVector;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_nnzPerVector, N * sizeof(int)));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDnnz(handle, CUSPARSE_DIRECTION_ROW, N, N, descrA[0], d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVector, &nnz[0]));

    // --- Host side number of nonzero elements per row
    int *h_nnzPerVector = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_nnzPerVector, d_nnzPerVector, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix = %i\n\n", nnz[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) printf("Number of nonzero elements in row %i = %i \n", i, h_nnzPerVector[i]);
    printf("\n");

    // --- Device side sparse matrix
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A[0], nnz[0] * sizeof(double)));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_RowIndices[0], (N + 1) * sizeof(int)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_ColIndices[0], nnz[0]  * sizeof(int)));

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDdense2csr(handle, N, N, descrA[0], d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVector, d_A[0], d_A_RowIndices[0], d_A_ColIndices[0]));

    // --- Host side sparse matrix
    double *h_A = (double *)malloc(nnz[0] * sizeof(double));        
    int *h_A_RowIndices = (int *)malloc((N + 1) * sizeof(*h_A_RowIndices));
    int *h_A_ColIndices = (int *)malloc(nnz[0] * sizeof(*h_A_ColIndices));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A, d_A[0], nnz[0] * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A_RowIndices, d_A_RowIndices[0], (N + 1) * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A_ColIndices, d_A_ColIndices[0], nnz[0] * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("\nOriginal matrix in CSR format\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nnz[0]; ++i) printf("A[%i] = %f ", i, h_A[i]); printf("\n");

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < (N + 1); ++i) printf("h_A_RowIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_A_RowIndices[i]); printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < nnz[0]; ++i) printf("h_A_ColIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_A_ColIndices[i]);    

}

/******************/
/* GRAPH COLORING */
/******************/
__global__ void setRowIndices(int *d_B_RowIndices, const int N) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    if (tid == N)       d_B_RowIndices[tid] = N;
    else if (tid < N)   d_B_RowIndices[tid] = tid;

}

__global__ void setB(double *d_B, const int N) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    if (tid < N)    d_B[tid] = 1.f;

}

void graphColoring(const cusparseHandle_t handle, const int nnz, const cusparseMatDescr_t descrA, const double fractionToColor, double *d_A, 
                   const int *d_A_RowIndices, const int *d_A_ColIndices, double **d_B, int **d_B_RowIndices, int **d_B_ColIndices, 
                   cusparseMatDescr_t *descrB, const int N) {

    cusparseColorInfo_t info;       cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateColorInfo(&info));

    int ncolors;
    int *d_coloring;        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_coloring, N * sizeof(double)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_B_ColIndices[0], N * sizeof(double)));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrcolor(handle, N, nnz, descrA, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, &fractionToColor, &ncolors, d_coloring,
                                       d_B_ColIndices[0], info));

    int *h_coloring     = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    int *h_B_ColIndices = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_coloring, d_coloring, N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_B_ColIndices, d_B_ColIndices[0], N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("h_coloring = %i; h_B_ColIndices = %i\n", h_coloring[i], h_B_ColIndices[i]);

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_B_RowIndices[0], (N + 1) * sizeof(int)));
    int *h_B_RowIndices = (int *)malloc((N + 1) * sizeof(double));
    setRowIndices<<<iDivUp(N + 1, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(d_B_RowIndices[0], N);

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_B_RowIndices, d_B_RowIndices[0], (N + 1) * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    printf("\n"); for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) printf("h_B_RowIndices = %i\n", h_B_RowIndices[i]);

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_B[0], N * sizeof(double)));
    double *h_B = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    setB<<<iDivUp(N, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(d_B[0], N);

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_B, d_B[0], N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    printf("\n"); for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("h_B = %f\n", h_B[i]);

    // --- Descriptor for sparse mutation matrix B
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrB[0]));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatType     (descrB[0], CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrB[0], CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO));  
}

/*************************/
/* MATRIX ROW REORDERING */
/*************************/
void matrixRowReordering(const cusparseHandle_t handle, int nnzA, int nnzB, int *nnzC, cusparseMatDescr_t descrA, cusparseMatDescr_t descrB, 
                         cusparseMatDescr_t *descrC, double *d_A, int *d_A_RowIndices, int *d_A_ColIndices, double *d_B, int *d_B_RowIndices, 
                         int *d_B_ColIndices, double **d_C, int **d_C_RowIndices, int **d_C_ColIndices, const int N) {

    // --- Descriptor for sparse matrix C
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrC[0]));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatType     (descrC[0], CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrC[0], CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO));  

    const int lda = N;                      // --- Leading dimension of dense matrix

    // --- Device side sparse matrix
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_C_RowIndices[0], (N + 1) * sizeof(int)));

    // --- Host side sparse matrices
    int *h_C_RowIndices = (int *)malloc((N + 1) * sizeof(int));

    // --- Performing the matrix - matrix multiplication
    int baseC;
    int *nnzTotalDevHostPtr = &nnzC[0]; 

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetPointerMode(handle, CUSPARSE_POINTER_MODE_HOST));

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseXcsrgemmNnz(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, N, N, descrB, nnzB, 
                                         d_B_RowIndices, d_B_ColIndices, descrA, nnzA, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, descrC[0], d_C_RowIndices[0], 
                                         nnzTotalDevHostPtr));
    if (NULL != nnzTotalDevHostPtr) nnzC[0] = *nnzTotalDevHostPtr;
    else {
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(&nnzC[0],  d_C_RowIndices + N, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(&baseC,    d_C_RowIndices,     sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        nnzC -= baseC;
    }
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_C_ColIndices[0], nnzC[0] * sizeof(int)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_C[0], nnzC[0] * sizeof(double)));
    double *h_C = (double *)malloc(nnzC[0] * sizeof(double));       
    int *h_C_ColIndices = (int *)malloc(nnzC[0] * sizeof(int));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrgemm(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, N, N, descrB, nnzB,
                                      d_B, d_B_RowIndices, d_B_ColIndices, descrA, nnzA, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, descrC[0],
                                      d_C[0], d_C_RowIndices[0], d_C_ColIndices[0]));

    double *h_C_dense = (double*)malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
    double *d_C_dense;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_C_dense, N * N * sizeof(double)));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsr2dense(handle, N, N, descrC[0], d_C[0], d_C_RowIndices[0], d_C_ColIndices[0], d_C_dense, N));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_C ,           d_C[0],            nnzC[0] * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_C_RowIndices, d_C_RowIndices[0], (N + 1) * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_C_ColIndices, d_C_ColIndices[0], nnzC[0] * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("\nResult matrix C in CSR format\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nnzC[0]; ++i) printf("C[%i] = %f ", i, h_C[i]); printf("\n");

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < (N + 1); ++i) printf("h_C_RowIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_C_RowIndices[i]); printf("\n");

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nnzC[0]; ++i) printf("h_C_ColIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_C_ColIndices[i]);   

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_C_dense, d_C_dense, N * N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
            printf("%f \t", h_C_dense[i * N + j]);
        printf("\n");
        }

}

/******************/
/* ROW REORDERING */
/******************/
void rowReordering(const cusparseHandle_t handle, int nnzA, cusparseMatDescr_t descrB, double *d_B, int *d_B_RowIndices, int *d_B_ColIndices, 
                   double *d_x_dense, double **d_y_dense, const int N) {

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_y_dense[0], N     * sizeof(double)));

    const double alpha = 1.;
    const double beta  = 0.;
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrmv(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, N, nnzA, &alpha, descrB, d_B, d_B_RowIndices, d_B_ColIndices, d_x_dense, 
                                    &beta, d_y_dense[0]));

    double *h_y_dense = (double*)malloc(N *     sizeof(double));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_y_dense,           d_y_dense[0],            N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("\nResult vector\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) printf("h_y[%i] = %f ", i, h_y_dense[i]); printf("\n");

}

/*****************************/
/* SOLVING THE LINEAR SYSTEM */
/*****************************/
void LUDecomposition(const cusparseHandle_t handle, int nnzC, cusparseMatDescr_t descrC, double *d_C, int *d_C_RowIndices, int *d_C_ColIndices, 
                     double *d_x_dense, double **d_y_dense, const int N) {

    /******************************************/
    /* STEP 1: CREATE DESCRIPTORS FOR L AND U */
    /******************************************/
    cusparseMatDescr_t      descr_L = 0; 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr (&descr_L)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descr_L, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatType     (descr_L, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatFillMode (descr_L, CUSPARSE_FILL_MODE_LOWER)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatDiagType (descr_L, CUSPARSE_DIAG_TYPE_UNIT)); 

    cusparseMatDescr_t      descr_U = 0; 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr (&descr_U)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descr_U, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatType     (descr_U, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatFillMode (descr_U, CUSPARSE_FILL_MODE_UPPER)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatDiagType (descr_U, CUSPARSE_DIAG_TYPE_NON_UNIT)); 

    /**************************************************************************************************/
    /* STEP 2: QUERY HOW MUCH MEMORY USED IN LU FACTORIZATION AND THE TWO FOLLOWING SYSTEM INVERSIONS */
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    csrilu02Info_t info_C = 0; cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateCsrilu02Info  (&info_C)); 
    csrsv2Info_t info_L = 0;   cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateCsrsv2Info    (&info_L)); 
    csrsv2Info_t info_U = 0;   cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateCsrsv2Info    (&info_U)); 

    int pBufferSize_M, pBufferSize_L, pBufferSize_U; 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrilu02_bufferSize(handle, N, nnzC, descrC, d_C, d_C_RowIndices, d_C_ColIndices, info_C, &pBufferSize_M)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_bufferSize (handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, nnzC, descr_L, d_C, d_C_RowIndices, d_C_ColIndices, info_L, &pBufferSize_L)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_bufferSize (handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, nnzC, descr_U, d_C, d_C_RowIndices, d_C_ColIndices, info_U, &pBufferSize_U)); 

    int pBufferSize = max(pBufferSize_M, max(pBufferSize_L, pBufferSize_U)); 
    void *pBuffer = 0; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&pBuffer, pBufferSize)); 

    /************************************************************************************************/
    /* STEP 3: ANALYZE THE THREE PROBLEMS: LU FACTORIZATION AND THE TWO FOLLOWING SYSTEM INVERSIONS */
    /************************************************************************************************/
    int structural_zero; 

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrilu02_analysis(handle, N, nnzC, descrC, d_C, d_C_RowIndices, d_C_ColIndices, info_C, CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_NO_LEVEL, pBuffer)); 
    cusparseStatus_t status = cusparseXcsrilu02_zeroPivot(handle, info_C, &structural_zero); 
    if (CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT == status){ printf("A(%d,%d) is missing\n", structural_zero, structural_zero); } 

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_analysis(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, nnzC, descr_L, d_C, d_C_RowIndices, d_C_ColIndices, info_L, CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_NO_LEVEL, pBuffer)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_analysis(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, nnzC, descr_U, d_C, d_C_RowIndices, d_C_ColIndices, info_U, CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_USE_LEVEL, pBuffer)); 

    /************************************/
    /* STEP 4: FACTORIZATION: A = L * U */
    /************************************/
    int numerical_zero; 

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrilu02(handle, N, nnzC, descrC, d_C, d_C_RowIndices, d_C_ColIndices, info_C, CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_NO_LEVEL, pBuffer)); 
    status = cusparseXcsrilu02_zeroPivot(handle, info_C, &numerical_zero); 
    if (CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT == status){ printf("U(%d,%d) is zero\n", numerical_zero, numerical_zero); } 

    /*********************/
    /* STEP 5: L * z = x */
    /*********************/
    // --- Allocating the intermediate result vector
    double *d_z_dense;      gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_z_dense, N * sizeof(double))); 

    const double alpha = 1.; 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_solve(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, nnzC, &alpha, descr_L, d_C, d_C_RowIndices, d_C_ColIndices, info_L, d_x_dense, d_z_dense, CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_NO_LEVEL, pBuffer)); 

    /*********************/
    /* STEP 5: U * y = z */
    /*********************/
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_y_dense[0], N * sizeof(double))); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_solve(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, nnzC, &alpha, descr_U, d_C, d_C_RowIndices, d_C_ColIndices, info_U, d_z_dense, d_y_dense[0], CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_USE_LEVEL, pBuffer));

    double *h_y_dense = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_y_dense, d_y_dense[0], N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    printf("\n\nFinal result\n");
    for (int k=0; k<N; k++) printf("x[%i] = %f\n", k, h_y_dense[k]);

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    // --- Initialize cuSPARSE
    cusparseHandle_t handle;    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreate(&handle));

    /*************************************************/
    /* SETTING UP THE ORIGINAL LINEAR SYSTEM PROBLEM */
    /*************************************************/
    const int N     = 4;                // --- Number of rows and columns

    double *h_A_dense;  double *h_x_dense;
    double *d_A_dense;  double *d_x_dense;
    setUpTheProblem(&h_A_dense, &h_x_dense, &d_A_dense, &d_x_dense, N);

    /************************/
    /* FROM DENSE TO SPARSE */
    /************************/
    //--- Descriptor for sparse matrix A
    cusparseMatDescr_t descrA;

    int *d_A_RowIndices, *d_A_ColIndices;   
    double *d_A;

    int nnzA;

    fromDenseToSparse(handle, d_A_dense, &d_A, &d_A_RowIndices, &d_A_ColIndices, &nnzA, &descrA, N);

    /******************/
    /* GRAPH COLORING */
    /******************/
    const double fractionToColor = 0.95;

    int *d_B_RowIndices, *d_B_ColIndices;   
    double *d_B;

    int nnzB;

    cusparseMatDescr_t descrB;      
    graphColoring(handle, nnzB, descrA, fractionToColor, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, &d_B, &d_B_RowIndices, &d_B_ColIndices, &descrB, N);

    /*************************/
    /* MATRIX ROW REORDERING */
    /*************************/
    int nnzC;

    int *d_C_RowIndices, *d_C_ColIndices;
    double *d_C;

    cusparseMatDescr_t descrC;
    matrixRowReordering(handle, nnzA, nnzB, &nnzC, descrA, descrB, &descrC, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, d_B, d_B_RowIndices, d_B_ColIndices, 
                        &d_C, &d_C_RowIndices, &d_C_ColIndices, N);

    /******************/
    /* ROW REORDERING */
    /******************/
    double *d_y_dense;
    rowReordering(handle, nnzA, descrB, d_B, d_B_RowIndices, d_B_ColIndices, d_x_dense, &d_y_dense, N);

    /*****************************/
    /* SOLVING THE LINEAR SYSTEM */
    /*****************************/
    double *d_xsol_dense;
    LUDecomposition(handle, nnzC, descrC, d_C, d_C_RowIndices, d_C_ColIndices, d_y_dense, &d_xsol_dense, N);

}
```